# tar compressing and decompressing

Tags: compression, tar

I am working on iMX6 Arm processor based hardware platform with embedded linux. I am using the  tar command to compress a directory containing 3 files. When I  try to decompress the folder to get back the three files I am facing different issues:

1. I get one or two files after decompressing.
2. The data in the original file and the decompressed file, there is data mismatch.

I am using these commands to create and decompress the tar file:

```
nohup tar -zcpf /home/root/upload_new_U1/unit1-`(date +%Y%m%d_%H-00)`.tar.gz upload_now_U1
tar -zxpf unit1-`(date +%Y%m%d_%H-00)`.tar.gz
```

Please help.

Comment: You should probably first assign the current day/time to a variable, otherwise it (at least the hour) might be different in the second command. I'm not saying this is the reason for the problem, but what you do doesn't always work.

Comment: I want to reframe my question. I tried without time-stamp, like a normal folder containing three files using the same command. Still I face the same problem.

Comment: OK, then I don't know what the problem could be. I would try with smaller and smaller files, then less and less files, until you can just barely still reproduce the problem. That way you might find the root cause. Also: is it always exactly the same, or sometimes different? What if you just list the contents of the tar file?